# How can I have MATLAB display a number that is being returned as Inf ( Infinity )?

Tags: matlab

I am working on a MATLAB program and was wondering how to get my return value when it is being displayed as **`Inf`** ( too large for MATLAB ).

```
% Question2
% Program is meant to calculate the product of all the odd numbers from 1 to 1000
% declare variable ‘product’ as zero
 product = 1.;
 % initialize counter, ‘n’, to 1000
 n = 1000;
 for i = 1:2:n
     product = product * i;
 end
 fprintf( 'The product of all the odd numbers from 1 to %d is %d\n', n, product )
```

Comment: You can use `prod(1 : 2 : n)` without the loop. And matlab is not very good for arbitrary precision calculations.

Comment: Will that get rid of inf and give me a real integer?

Comment: Nope... `n` is too large!

Comment: No way, huh? Man, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out a way to do it but that's probably because I'm an idiot. Thanks peeps!

Comment: @KyleRogers - I misinformed you.  You can compute this, but you need to use `vpa`.  Check out my answer.

Comment: Alright, I do have the 64 bit Matlab. I'm not quite sure what you mean though, Cheery. Anyway that you can explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute that number, but not natively.  You'll need to use MATLAB's variable precision arithmetic methods or [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).  First, create your vector from 1 to 1000 in steps of 2, then encapsulate it as a `vpa` object.  After that, follow Cheery's advice and call `prod` on this sequence.  As such, try something like this:

```
>> A = vpa(1:2:1000);
>> prod(A)

ans =

1.007483297637508540040389173923e1283
```

As such, this is telling us that the number is 1.00748... x 10<sup>1283</sup>... wow!